# Can I reduce the spacing between a function and a big paren to that between it and normal parens?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, brackets

So if I want to apply some function to a big and complex expression, I'd like to use `\left( \right)` because it scales the parentheses to match the expressions height. However, when doing this, extra space is introduced.

Compare `f(x)` and `f\left(x\right)`:
[image]

Source:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\begin{document}
\( f(x) \) (small) \\ \( f\left(x\right) \) (large)
\end{document}
```

Comment: see the `mleftright` package, the extra spacing is sadly a consequence of how `\left....\right` works. (of course, one would never use `\left...\right` in the example you give here, but I understand your point)

Comment: @campa No, but the comment by @daleif suggesting `mleftright` has fully resolved my problem.

Comment: That's actually one of the answers to that question.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen. Thanks. In that case, yes, it does answer my question.